# SQL Loop Thru Results and Update Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find a more efficient way of looping through my table that doesn't create such a bottleneck updating a row based on results in previous rows that may, or may not, have already been updated by the same logic.

Currently I am using the below code to loop thru my table.  A picture of the sample results are below.

Basically if the logic sees step 8 and sees that step 10 or 11 happened prior this step then renumber this step to step 14.

Im not sure if Cursor would work better.  The table is indexed and depending on the data range the table will have over a million rows of data looking to evaluate this logic against 20 different ProcessID's.

Thank you for all your help!

```
DECLARE @RowsToProcess55  int
DECLARE @CurrentRow55     int
DECLARE @SelectCol155     int

DECLARE @table155 TABLE (RowID int not null primary key identity(1,1), col1 int )  
INSERT into @table155 (col1) SELECT ID FROM ##HEFStepRenumber
SET @RowsToProcess55=@@ROWCOUNT

SET @CurrentRow55=0
WHILE @CurrentRow55<@RowsToProcess55
BEGIN
SET @CurrentRow55=@CurrentRow55+1
SELECT 
    @SelectCol155=col1
    FROM @table155
    WHERE RowID=@CurrentRow55

Update  a
Set StepIDNew = (Select Case 
when a.ProcessID = 1 and a.StepID = 9 and (Select distinct StepID from ##HEFStepRenumber as b where b.EventID = a.EventID and b.UserDispName = a.UserDispName and b.Dates = a.Dates and b.TriggerLogID < a.TriggerLogID and StepID = 30)=30 then 31 
when a.ProcessID = 1 and a.StepID = 8 and (Select distinct StepID from ##HEFStepRenumber as b where b.EventID = a.EventID and b.UserDispName = a.UserDispName and b.Dates = a.Dates and b.TriggerLogID < a.TriggerLogID and StepID = 25)=25 then 26
when a.ProcessID = 1 and a.StepID = 4 and a.TriggerDisplayName <> 'MS Adjud_Open Doc Hub' and (Select distinct StepID from ##HEFStepRenumber as b where b.EventID = a.EventID and b.UserDispName = a.UserDispName and b.Dates = a.Dates and b.TriggerLogID < a.TriggerLogID and b.TriggerDisplayName <> 'MS Adjud_Open Doc Hub' and StepID = 20)=20 then 24
when a.ProcessID = 1 and a.StepID = 9 and (Select distinct StepID from ##HEFStepRenumber as b where b.EventID = a.EventID and b.UserDispName = a.UserDispName and b.Dates = a.Dates and b.TriggerLogID < a.TriggerLogID and StepID = 20)=20 then 23
when a.ProcessID = 1 and a.StepID = 8 and (Select distinct StepID from ##HEFStepRenumber as b where b.EventID = a.EventID and b.UserDispName = a.UserDispName and b.Dates = a.Dates and b.TriggerLogID < a.TriggerLogID and StepID = 20)=20 then 22
when a.ProcessID = 1 and a.StepID = 4 and a.TriggerDisplayName <> 'MS Adjud_Open Doc Hub' and  (Select count(distinct StepIDNew) from ##HEFStepRenumber as b where b.EventID = a.EventID and b.UserDispName = a.UserDispName and b.Dates = a.Dates and b.TriggerLogID < a.TriggerLogID and b.TriggerDisplayName <> 'MS Adjud_Open Doc Hub' and StepIDNew in(13,16,17))>=1 then 21
when a.ProcessID = 1 and a.StepID = 5 and (Select distinct StepIDNew from ##HEFStepRenumber as b where b.EventID = a.EventID and b.UserDispName = a.UserDispName and b.Dates = a.Dates and b.TriggerLogID < a.TriggerLogID and StepIDNew = 13)=13 then 17
when a.ProcessID = 1 and a.StepID = 10 and (Select distinct StepIDNew from ##HEFStepRenumber as b where b.EventID = a.EventID and b.UserDispName = a.UserDispName and b.Dates = a.Dates and b.TriggerLogID < a.TriggerLogID and StepIDNew = 13)=13 then 16
when a.ProcessID = 1 and a.StepID = 9 and (Select count(distinct StepID) from ##HEFStepRenumber as b where b.EventID = a.EventID and b.UserDispName = a.UserDispName and b.Dates = a.Dates and b.TriggerLogID < a.TriggerLogID and StepID in (10,11))>=1 then 15
when a.ProcessID = 1 and a.StepID = 8 and (Select count(distinct StepID) from ##HEFStepRenumber as b where b.EventID = a.EventID and b.UserDispName = a.UserDispName and b.Dates = a.Dates and b.TriggerLogID < a.TriggerLogID and StepID in (10,11))>=1 then 14
when a.ProcessID = 1 and a.StepID = 4 and a.TriggerDisplayName <>'MS Adjud_Open Doc Hub' and (Select count(distinct StepID) from ##HEFStepRenumber as b where b.EventID = a.EventID and b.UserDispName = a.UserDispName and b.Dates = a.Dates and b.TriggerLogID < a.TriggerLogID and StepID in(10,11) and b.TriggerDisplayName <> 'MS Adjud_Open Doc Hub')>=1 then 13
else a.StepID end)
From ##HEFStepRenumber a
where a.ID = @CurrentRow55
END
```

[Sample Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vod0d.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough points to comment so

what if your query in case statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT StepID
FROM ##HEFStepRenumber AS b
WHERE b.EventID = a.EventID
    AND b.UserDispName = a.UserDispName
    AND b.Dates = a.Dates
    AND b.TriggerLogID < a.TriggerLogID
    AND StepID = 30
```

returns more than 1 value?